# Unexpected redirection behavior when using multiple Devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am conditionally redirecting to SSL in my app. I User and Admin models, both configured with `devise_for`. I'm using `rails_admin` with the Admin model, and my own CMS stuff for the Users model.

In `application_controller` I have a before filter `check_ssl`, which redirects to SSL if `user_signed_in? || controller_name == 'registrations' || controller_name == 'sessions'` and `!request.ssl?`.

I've verified the logic by watching my logs.

### Problem

- When I try to access /admin to get my RailsAdmin interface, it detects that I'm not logged in and correctly redirects to `/admins/sign_in`.
- My SSL `before_filter` runs and sees that it's not currently SSL. My logs:

  ```
  ssl? is false and fullpath is /admins/sign_in
  should use ssl
  Redirected to https://foo.com/login
  ssl? is true and fullpath is /login
  ```

`/login` is the login path for my `User` model, not my `Admin` model.
The redirect code is literally:
`redirect_to({:protocol => 'https'}, :flash => flash)`
What is going on here?

Comment: Have you tried to actually re-set the url with the url from the request object? `redirect_to({ :url => request.url, :protocol => 'https'}, :flash => flash}`

Comment: `url => request.url` just passes passes `url` as a query param, but manually constructing the path like `"#{protocol}://#{host}#{request.fullpath}"` did work correctly. Question is: why can't I just use `{:protocol => 'https'}`?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work correctly I ended up having to manually build my redirect url:

```
  "#{protocol}://#{host}#{request.fullpath}"
```